# Peculiar behaviour of jquery for drop down

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a small jquery which for dynamically creating form fields based on drop down selection.
I noticed a peculiar behaviour i.e. when the page is loaded for first time ..it behaves good i.e. whenever you change the selection in drop down ..respective dynamic form fields are added/removed..

But when i again refresh the page and try ..the jquery does not do the job ..why is it so ?
And another important point is the same code works in one rails project and does not in another another rails project.

JQUERY

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
  // hide divs first
  $('form .toggle').hide();

  // get value from dropdown
  var divClass = $('.dropdown').val().toLowerCase();

  // show necessary div
  $('.' + divClass).show();
});
```

VIEW from Rails

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "new" %>

<%= simple_form_for @obj do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :receiver_email, :collection => ['Human', 'Event'], :input_html => { :class => 'dropdown'} %>

  <div class="human" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :receiver_mobile %>
  </div>

  <div class="event" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :reason %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Are there any errors appearing the console?

Comment: no there are no errors.. one more question..when i am trying to print the .value() of drop down in another rails ..it shows the value as 'zero' but where as in another rails application it perfectly shows the value selected in drop down ...why is this happening ?